# Why the following expression is true.

Tags: probability

\begin{align}
 \mathbb{P}[h>Tr^\alpha(\sigma^2+I_r)|r]=\mathbb{E}_{I_r}\big[\mathbb{P}[h>Tr^\alpha(\sigma^2+I_r)|r,I_r]\big]
\end{align}

I do not know the reason why the above expression is true. 
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation